# Apache Camel: how to read integer property in file uri component

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am trying to read integer value of a property but I am getting errors. 
I did read "Using Property Placeholders for Any Kind of Attribute in the XML DSL" in the link http://camel.apache.org/properties.html. But I don't understand the usage of it inside the file uri component.

```
<from id="listenIncomingFiles" uri="file:{{PFlowIn_AEROW}}?include=.*\.xml&amp;prop:delay={{PFlowScanDelay}}&amp;noop=false&amp;preMove={{PMessDir}}"/>

Failed to create route .... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: file://D:/data/AeroW/OUT?include=.*\.xml&noop=false&preMove=D%3A%2Fdata%2FMessageDir&prop%3Adelay=2000 due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: file://D:/data/AeroW/OUT?include=.*\.xml&noop=false&preMove=D%3A%2Fdata%2FMessageDir&prop%3Adelay=2000 due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{prop:delay=2000}]
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
<from id="listenIncomingFiles" uri="file:{{PFlowIn_AEROW}}?include=.*\.xml&amp;delay={{PFlowScanDelay}}&amp;noop=false&amp;preMove={{PMessDir}}"/>
```

instead of

```
<from id="listenIncomingFiles" uri="file:{{PFlowIn_AEROW}}?include=.*\.xml&amp;prop:delay={{PFlowScanDelay}}&amp;noop=false&amp;preMove={{PMessDir}}"/>
```

Namely "prop:delay={{PFlowScanDelay}}" should be replaced by "delay={{PFlowScanDelay}}". No need for the "prop:" prefix when setting consumer properties.

Comment: I get compile time error in IDE "The parameter delay requires a numeric value."

Comment: Is it just your IDE complaining? If so you can just ignore it. If you are just looking to inject properties in your endpoint URI I suggest you rather use Property place holder http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html.

If this still doesn't work could you share your configuration file or small project?

Comment: Yes, its complaining and I have read the section "Using Property Placeholders for Any Kind of Attribute in the XML DSL" in the link you provided. But it isn't still working.

Comment: This is an example route  where PScanDelay is parameter is defined in theblueprint property file in etc folder<route>
       <from uri="file:c:/work/input?delay={{PScanDelay}}&noop=true"/>
       <to uri="file:c:/work/output"/>
       </from>
       </route>